# How to return a struct which contains an array pointer from a function?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have this struct and declaration in *.h* file,

```
struct strct
{
    int *arry;
};
strct func01();
```

and this function in *.cpp* file,

```
strct func01()
{
    int temp_arry[] = {5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
    strct rtrn;
    rtrn.arry = temp_arry;
    return rtrn;
}
```

and i call the function like,

```
strct test = func01();
printf("%d", test.arry);
```

It prints some random numbers. I want to print the full array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before we start, let's recall the behavior of the `sizeof` operator:
**Case of :**  `int *`

```
int *arry;  
int iSize =  sizeof (arry); <-- Return size of pointer and NOT number of elements
```

**Case of :**  `int []`

```
int temp_arry[] = {5, 6, 7, 8, 9}; 
int iSize = sizeof (temp_arry); <-- Return total memory size allocated for 5 elements
```

You understand now that the composition of your structure **does not allow you** to determine the **number of elements** of your `int *arry` struct member. Therefore, you don't know how many element you should display.

If you wish to keep your program without using the STL: vector, array, ... you must complete your structure as follows:

```
struct strct
{
    int size; // Contains the number of elements to use
    int *arry;
};
strct func01();


strct func01()
{
    strct rtrn;
    int tab_size = 5;

    // it is a temp variable. Destroyed when function ends.You can not use it !
    int temp_arry[] = {5, 6, 7, 8, 9}; 

    // This table is allocated with new and can be used
    int *permanent_arry = new int [tab_size];
    for (int i=0;  i<tab_size; i++)
        permanent_arry[i] = i;

    rtrn.arry = permanent_arry; 
    rtrn.size = tab_size; 

    return rtrn;
}

int main ()
{
    strct test = func01();
    for (int i=0; i<test.size; i++)
      printf("%d ", test.arry[i]);  

     // dont forget to delete memory 
     delete [] test.arry;
}
```

Comment: `sizeof` is not a function

Comment: It's not super important for the point you were making, but if you call it a function people want to make their own functions that work the same way and get confused when they can't.  Correctly describe it as an operator, and the question about making your own is succinctly handled by the fact that C++ allows customizing behavior of many operators but not creation of new operators.

Comment: @BenVoigt as operator or  unary operator  is better yes

Answer (score 0):

First, this code is wrong because:

1. the lifetime of `temp_arry[]` is end after `func01` returns.
2. you are printing a pointer, not an array.

Second, if you want to print the full array, you'd better redesign your code, for example, you may use vector to clean up your code. (this code needs C++ 11)

```cpp
struct strct
{
    std::vector<int> arry;
};
strct func01();
```

```cpp
strct func01()
{
    std::vector<int> temp_arry = {5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
    strct rtrn;
    rtrn.arry = temp_arry;
    return rtrn;
}
```

```cpp
strct test = func01();
for(auto i : test)
   std::cout << i << " ";
```

Note: most of the time there's no point to use built-in arrays as return value, even though it will decay to a pointer prvalue.

Comment: This doesn't work, as `std::array<int>` is missing the size information, which must thus be specified in advance.

Comment: @BenVoigt, True. I didn't mentioned it, i'll edit it right away, thanks

Comment: ~~mentioned~~ -> noticed